# Analyzer for compression algorithms (or tools)

Tags: c, file, compression

This file contains the main functions of my tool, [rac](http://github.com/matteodelseppia/rac). In particular, I care a lot about the Shannon function.

Would you please give some hints to make the file  cleaner? I have a perversion for concise and good indented code.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "headers/utils.h"

double ccount(char * foo)
{
  FILE * file = fopen(foo, "r");
  int a = 0, b;
  while ((b = getc(file)) != EOF)
    a++;

  fclose(file);
  return a;
}

int cmp(double foo, double bar)
{
  if (foo >= bar)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

double ratio(double foo, double bar)
{
  return (100*(foo - bar)/ foo);
}

void stat(char * file, double vector[256])
  {
    int c;
    FILE * ftopen = fopen(file, "r");
    while ((c = getc(ftopen)) != EOF)
      {
        if (c >= 0 && c <= 256) 
            vector[c]++;  
      }

      fclose(ftopen);
  }

void freq(char * foo, double vector[256])
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    if (vector[i] == 0)
      continue;
    else
      {
        vector[i] = (vector[i] / ccount(foo));
      }
  }
}

double shannon(double vector[256])
{
  int i;
  double shan = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    if (vector[i] == 0.0)
      continue;
    else
      {
        shan = shan + (log2(pow(vector[i], vector[i]))); 
      }
  }
  return (shan * -1.0); //entropy of the file
}
```

Comment: In addition to what both Martin R and I already commented on, if the program is calling both ccount() and stat() a better choice would be to open the file once and pass the file pointer to both functions. I agree with Martin R that there are faster and simpler ways to get the number of characters in the file by using simple system calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MAGIC NUMBERS**
The number 256 is used in multiple places as an array size. Rather than using the raw number
256, it would be better to use a symbolic constant. Raw numbers in code are sometimes referred to as magic numbers, because it isn't clear what they mean.
There are at least two reasons for this,

1. It identifies what the number means.
2. If at some point in the future the number has to be changed for all uses, the code only  needs to be changed in one place.

An Example in C:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 256

void stat(char * file, double vector[ARRAY_SIZE])
{
    int c;
    FILE * ftopen = fopen(file, "r");
    while ((c = getc(ftopen)) != EOF)
      {
        if (c >= 0 && c <= ARRAY_SIZE)
            vector[c]++;
      }

      fclose(ftopen);
}
```

An Example in C++:

```
constexpr int ARRAY_SIZE = 256;
```

**Use Meaningful Variable and Function Names**
The code contains `foo` and `bar` in a number of places. These are not meaningful names.
The names should indicate what the variables are, so that if you or someone else needs
to change the code 2 years in the future it is an easy task rather than having to go
through all the code to see what needs to be changed.

Another exmaple of this is the function `ccount()`, which could be renamed file_size().

A third example is the array `vector`. Other than array if doubles it is not clear what
this array is used for.

**Inconsistent Coding Style**
In a professional setting where multiple people may have to maintain the code it is best
to be as consistent as possible.

The else clauses almost always have `{ block`}` but the if statements do not.
This is true whether or not the block contains multiple statement or not.
You should choose one way or the other.

In the `for` loops the `{` is immediately under the `for`, but in the `else` clauses it
is indented. Choose one or the other. The most common usage is how you do the for loops.

This is partially a matter of choice, I use `{ block }` on all control statements:

```
if ()
{
}
else
{
}

for ()
{
}

while ()
{
}

do
{
} while ();
```

I do this even for single statements because if the code needs to be updated by adding a statement
to a block it is easier for anyone to see where the line of code should be inserted. This was
also required as part of a coding standard at a company where I worked.

**Empty Clauses in IF/ELSE**
In the function shannon() the code contains:

```
    if (vector[i] == 0.0)
      continue;
    else
      {
        shan = shan + (log2(pow(vector[i], vector[i])));
      }
```

This would be clearer if it was written

```
    if (vector[i] != 0.0)
      {
        shan = shan + (log2(pow(vector[i], vector[i])));
      }
```

An else clause can be added at a later time if it is needed. The if portion of the current
implementation is meaningless and would be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, i needed all those hints. Really appreciated, I'm reviewing all my code right now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @pacmaninbw already said:

The return value of `fopen()` is not checked. It will be `NULL` if 
the file does not exist or the caller has no read permission. You have
 to decide how to handle that. Another option would be to open the
file in `main()` and pass the file handle to your functions.

A simpler  method to get the size of a file is using `stat()`
(or `fstat()` if you already have a handle to the file).
This is also much faster, because it only queries the filesystem, without
reading the entire file.

The `cmp()` function can be simplified to

```
int cmp(double foo, double bar)
{
  return foo >= bar;
}
```

because in C, the result of a comparison operator is either `0`
or `1`. In fact that is so simple that you probably don't need a
dedicated function for that purpose.

The return value of `getc()` is either `EOF`, or an `unsigned char`
converted to an `int`. In other words, if a `char` has 8 bit (which
is the case on all Posix-compatible platforms) then the return value
can only be `EOF` or an integer in the range `0 ... 255`, so there
is no need for a check

```
if (c >= 0 && c <= 256)
```

(and you probably meant `c < 256` here).

If you cannot assume that a `char` has 8 bits then use
`1 << CHAR_BIT` as the array size, not `256`.

In the `freq()` function,  at

```
    vector[i] = (vector[i] / ccount(foo));
```

the file size it computed for each loop iteration. Better compute
it once and store it in a local variable.

In the `shannon()` function

```
    shan = shan + (log2(pow(vector[i], vector[i])));
```

*should be* (as I understand it from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition)

```
    shan = shan + log2(vector[i]) * vector[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for all, really. The shannon function is right, i'm just using a logarithm property. The original is H(x) = sum(Pi*log2(Pi) where P is the frequency of a symbol and i is an index from 0 and 256.

Comment: @MatteoDelSeppia Since \$\log a^b = (\log a) * b\$, @MartinR's formula is correct and faster than using `pow()`.